# Office365 resource end points for O365-D-vnext (dedicated, not multi-tenants) deployment

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365

We are having issues with obtaining access tokens for Sharepoint/Exchange resources for a non-multi-tenan Office365 deployment.

This tenant has an O365-D-vnext (dedicated, not multi-tenants) environment which seems to use a different resource end points for sharepoint and exchange, and possibly the management APIs as well.

We use the 'client credential flow' (app-only) to authenticate the global admin for this tenant.  The authentication went through, and we got back an auth token (which we discard as it’s not applicable in app-only authentication flow) and tenant-id (we verified the tenant id with the customer).  We then tried to get tokens for 3 different APIs using

> login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/token

Here is where we are at with this:

1) We were able to get token for

> https://graph.windows.net

and access the active directory groups (we should be able to fetch the users as well)

2) We were able to obtain an access token for exchange resource endpoint

> https://outlook.office365.com/

but when we tried to use it, we got 404 for users that we know have mailboxes.  We are not sure if outlook.office365.com works for O365-D-vnext (dedicated, not multi-tenants) environment.

3) We were able to get token for

> https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com"

but when we tried to use the token to access user’s Onedrive, it returned this error: `{“error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Invalid audience Uri 'https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/'}` . We were told by our customer that this endpoint would not work for their non-multi-tenants environment.
We subsequently tried a couple of other vanity URIs that the users of this customer use to access their sharepoint onedrive documents.  But we were NOT able to get token for the URIs provided by our customers.  We received the following error when using these URIs provided:

```
{"error":"invalid_resource","error_description":"AADSTS50001: The application named https://<tenant-my-site>.com was not found in the tenant named https://<tenant>-my.sharepoint.com/. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant.  You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.\r\nTrace ID: … ”error_codes":[50001] …}
```

Any ideas on how to get access tokens for this type of deployments?

Comment: Have you registered your app in Azure AD (AAD) for your o365 tenant ? This is a must to do step otherwise AAD could not recognize your app. I can see that the error message is showing that you may not use the tenant.

Comment: Yes, otherwise I won't be able to perform step 1 above.  Also, our app works with all other tenants that have multi-tenants Office365 deployments.